# Get emails from Google contacts using a range of sheets cell values

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get emails from my Google contacts list using a range of cell values.
I've managed to do this with one value but not with a range/list of values.

In my example the cell G2 contains the name John Doe, I have managed to get the value from G2, search my contacts and return the corresponding email. The next step is to then use that return value and write it to another cell in the same sheet, I have also achieved this (writes the email address to N2).

I can't figure out how to do this for a range of of cells, I've tried numerous different approaches but keep getting errors.

The below code works perfectly only for the first cell value, I've tried changing the range to (2, 7, 10, 1) to get the first 10 cell values, and its seems that part works fine, but I'm not sure what the correct method is to then go through this array and get the email addresses, and lastly running a loop to write the addresses to a range of cells.

To sum up I'm trying to get a range of names from G2:G12, convert these names to email addresses, and write the results to N2:N12.

My example below can be reproduced by copying the code into a new sheets doc, nameing the sheet "Main", adding a name to the G2 cell and running the code.

```
function getEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Main');
  var EmailRange = sheet.getRange(2, 7, 1, 1)
  var EmailAddress = EmailRange.getValues()
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName(EmailAddress);
  var email = contacts[0].getEmails()[0].getAddress();
    Logger.log(email);
  return email
  
  }


  
function writeEmailsToSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Main');
  var results = getEmail();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 14, 1, 1);
  range.setValue(results);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what errors do you get? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Lorena, I added a little summary of the expected behaviour and the minimal example would be to just copy the code into Sheets and test it. I've tried so many different things I don't know where to start. I think it's better to just hope for a solution to the problem than to list my failures.

Answer (score 1):

To give you an idea, you can try the following script:

**UPDATE**

Here is the updated script, you can use the [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) statement. This will break the iteration in the loop if the condition occurs and will continue with the next one.

```js
function getEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Main');
  var emailRange = sheet.getRange("G2:G12")
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

  for (var i=0; i<emailAddress.length; i++){
    var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName(emailAddress[i]);
    if (contacts != ""){
      var email = contacts[0].getEmails()[0].getAddress();
      sheet.getRange(i+2,14).setValue(email)
    }
    else{
      sheet.getRange(i+2,14).setValue("Not found") 
      continue
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it works great. The only problem is that some of the values are returning as undefined and that breaks the loop. I'm not sure why they are returning as undefined, the contact information should be OK but thats a problem I can investigate myself. Is there a way to skip errors/undefined values and go to the next loop? Maybe using forEach() ?

Comment: @adam try with the updated script